C# Add Label to method which will be used in a combobox and interpreted as that method when selected
Is there an annotation or another way in C# to add a label="Label of Method Name" which can be used as a reference by a form when populating a combobox, and then when that label-of-method-name is selected C# knows to use the method?
For example:
public class FinancialAnalysisUtility 
{
    **[Label = "Annual Percentage Yield"]**
    public String annualPercentageYield(InterestRatePerPeriod intRatePerPeriod, NumberOfPeriods numberOfPeriods)
    {
        String results = "0";

        Time.TimePeriodUtility.interestRatePerPeriodConversion(intRatePerPeriod, numberOfPeriods.periodType, false);

        results = calc.divideNumbers(intRatePerPeriod.rateValuePerPeriodAsDecimal, numberOfPeriods.numberOfPeriods);
        results = calc.addNumbers("1", results);
        results = calc.exponent(results, numberOfPeriods.numberOfPeriods);
        results = calc.subtractNumbers(results, "1");

        results = calc.convertDecimalToPercentage(results);

        return results;
    }
}

Then in the FinancialAnalysis form, upon initiation, the code can get all labels in FinancialAnalysisUtility class and populate a combobox with the labels which, when selected, will resolve to the actual method?
I would like to avoid trying to remember having to manually add the label to a Dictionary or List and then having to remember to update the method which actually does the interpretation from that label to the actual method each time a new method is added to the FinancialAnalysisUtility class.
I've looked into Reflection and Type, but not seeing anything yet which I can utilize for this. There are a couple of options I've seen listed, but all require manual intervention and if I add a new method, but forget to add it to the method which actually handles the interpretation
If there aren't any ideas, I can use the below suggestion as it will accommodate what I need.
How to dynamically assign method combobox

You can always write your own Attribute.

Good idea. I'll try that. Thank you.

Worked like a charm
